# How to delete an object in SFML

Tags: visual-c++, sfml

I try to delete a square when I input the number as "1" into the program. How can I delete it?

```
sf::RectangleShape rec1(sf::Vector2f(50, 100));
rec1.setPosition(200, 700 );
rec1.setFillColor(sf::Color(100, 250, 50));
window.draw(rec1);

int num;
cout << "Please enter a number: ";
cin >> num;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFML itself won't track what's drawn on screen – you'll have to do that yourself – and you're supposed to redraw the window contents when needed.

A basic "main loop" for a SFML based program would typically look like this:

```
while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        // Handle events here
    }

    // Update your program logic here

    window.clear();

    // Draw your stuff here

    window.display();
}
```

Depending on what you draw, you determine what's visible on screen. So if you want your rectangle to no longer appear, simply no longer call `window.draw(rectangle);`. How you achieve this – e.g. by removing the rectangle from a `std::vector<sf::Drawable*>` that's iterated over while drawing – is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete it when you created it like that. you can color it as transparent using `sf::Color::Transparent` and it will become unseenable.

If you want to delete it. you have to make it a pointer first. or wrap it out of a class that handles it.

```
auto rect = make_unique<sf::Rectangle>(sf::Vector2f(50, 100));
```

and then use std::unique_ptr::reset() to delete it.

```
rect.reset();
```